# Using Sinon SinonStubbedInstance with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sinon, stub

I'm using `sinon` to stub an instance of express-`Request`.
It looks something like this:

```
let req = sinon.createStubInstance(Request);
```

My method accepts `req: Request` but my IDE complains about me using `SinonStubbedInstance<Request>` rather than `Request`.
I've tried using `req as Request` but I still get a warning about 'may be a mistake' and that I should first cast to `unknown` and only then to `Request`.

I actually don't need anything from this parameter so I really just want to stub it quickly and easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using it in the call to your method, just cast it:

```
myMethod(req as any);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this was posed 3 years ago, but since the only answer given is wrong, I feel obliged to comment, for someone else might benefit from it.

It's strongly discouraged to use as any and your compiler should complain about this (unless you have a very good reason not to, you should use strict compiler option).
Casting to unknown and then to your type seems unintuitive, but it is a cleaner way than casting to any. If you use any you might be better off not using typescript at all.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any

Consider doing

```
let req: SinonStubbedInstance<Request> & Request = sinon.createStubInstance(Request);
```

instead.

P.S.: Also, the use of let seems suspicious (sure cannot use const?), but that's a different topic.